# Typescript - Get Types of Child Interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have types like below.

```
export interface GetCategoryBySlugQuery {
  // Get specific Category by the id
  getCategory:  {
    id: string,
    name: string | null,
    image: string | null,
    description: string | null,
  } | null,
};
```

I want to reference type of `getCategory` from `GetCategoryBySlugQuery` interface to my variable without modifying the types of interface `GetCategoryBySlugQuery`.

Actually, I can achieve what I wanted by doing some dirt way like

```
const categorySchema: GetCategoryBySlugQuery = ({} as GetCategoryBySlugQuery)
const categoryObject: typeof categorySchema.getCategory = ({} as typeof categorySchema.getCategory)
// This is I'm successfully get what I want with a hack way
const myvariable: typeof categoryObject
```

How can I achieve it in a good way without edit the interface types because the type is generated by `apollo-codegen` and I should'nt edit it? Any solution?

Comment: You can define a separate type for `getCategory` and use it in the `GetCategoryBySlugQuery` and everywhere else.

Comment: The types are generated by `apollo-codegen` and I shouldn't edit the types.

Comment: Thanks, Hardik, I don't know the keyword.

Comment: I also didn't know the keyword. We are here for learning :)